# How to MATCH in the first column of a 2 dimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to reference the first column of the array kw30array in this match lookup? I read that if you set the row to 0 then it will only reference the column but after trying this it did not work. ie. kw30array(0,1) as the range.

Also, is it necessary to state 'worksheetfunction' since I am using an array and not the worksheet?

Thank you

```
For i = 2 To kw90rowcount
j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(kw90array(i, 1), kw30array, 0)
If IsError(j) Then
    kw90array(i, 32) = "-"
    kw90array(i, 33) = "-"
    kw90array(i, 34) = "-"
    kw90array(i, 37) = "-"
    kw90array(i, 38) = "-"
Else:
    kw90array(i, 32) = kw30array(j, 10)
    kw90array(i, 33) = kw30array(j, 12)
    kw90array(i, 34) = kw30array(j, 14)
    kw90array(i, 37) = kw30array(j, 11)
    kw90array(i, 38) = kw30array(j, 17)
End If
Next i
```

Comment: `Application.Index(kw30array,0,1)` .. will give you first column of that array.

Comment: A 2D array obtained **from a range** (you don't show how  the array is loaded, I just suppose that...) has `LBound` = 1. So `kw30array(0,1)` does not have a real row reference, it will certainly raise an error. Now, if you need a slice of a column (an array of the first row of the `kw30array` array) you should proceed as was recommended in the above code. `Dim arr` `arr = Application.Index(kw30array,0,1)`. Or if you need to match a value in the first array column you should write `j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(kw90array(i, 1), Application.Index(kw30array), 0)`

Comment: Maybe review this question for a suggestion on improving your lookup performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Application.Match` Faster with a Range

- You have to use `Application.Match` to be able to use `IsError` or `IsNumeric`.
- If `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` 'doesn't find a match', a run-time error will occur. Handling this is more complicated so I abandoned it for good.
- Here's one way to handle your issue:

```vb
Dim kw30first As Variant: kw30first = Application.Index(kw30array, 0, 1)
Dim rIndex As Variant
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To kw90rowcount
    rIndex = Application.Match(kw90array(i, 1), kw30first, 0)
    If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
        kw90array(i, 32) = kw30array(rIndex, 10)
        kw90array(i, 33) = kw30array(rIndex, 12)
        kw90array(i, 34) = kw30array(rIndex, 14)
        kw90array(i, 37) = kw30array(rIndex, 11)
        kw90array(i, 38) = kw30array(rIndex, 17)
    Else
        kw90array(i, 32) = "-"
        kw90array(i, 33) = "-"
        kw90array(i, 34) = "-"
        kw90array(i, 37) = "-"
        kw90array(i, 38) = "-"
    End If
Next i
```

- A few days ago [I learned from Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240854/a-faster-alternative-to-my-vlookup-block-of-code/68242814?noredirect=1#comment120619752_68242814) that `Application.Match` is about 10 times slower on an array than on a range. Shortly after I proved it. So you should consider doing something like this:

```vb
   Dim fcrg As Range: Set fcrg = kw30rng.Columns(1) ' First Column Range
   '''
   rIndex = Application.Match(kw90array(i, 1), fcrg, 0)
```

But still, use the array `kw30array` in the `If` statement.

Comment: Thank you. Still trying to wrap my head around this. Is there a way to just say that range kw30first is equal to the first column of the array kw30array? I could then reference this range when running the match.  I only ask because I am not sure if I can grasp entirely what you are showing above, even though I have no doubt it is better...    rng = kw30rng.Columns(1)     and     rng = Application.Index(kw30array, 0, 1)    are both giving errors...

Comment: The first has to be `Dim rng As Range: Set rng = kw30rng.Columns(1)` (like my `fcrg`), while the second is not a range: `Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = Application.Index(kw30array, 0, 1)` (like my `kw30First`). Here I am just assuming that the `kw30array` did also come from `reading` a range, but I don't know for sure. Maybe adding the rest of the code could help so we can see how you got the data into `kw30array`.